# Heroku: database migration does not create tables

Tags: django, heroku

During database migration, Heroku does not create all the tables specified in the models.py in every apps. The followings are the outputs of `manage.py migrations` and `manage.py migrate` (Sorry I have to list all the messages in order to make things clearer):

```
$ heroku run python3 manage.py makemigrations
Running `python3 manage.py makemigrations` attached to terminal... up, run.1919
Migrations for 'customer':
  0001_initial.py:
    - Create model Company
    - Create model Customer
Migrations for 'basicData':
  0001_initial.py:
    - Create model Bus
    - Create model ChargeStandard
    - Create model Employee
    - Create model Flight
    - Create model Phrase
Migrations for 'schedule':
  0001_initial.py:
    - Create model DriverVacation
    - Create model Schedule
Migrations for 'reserve':
  0001_initial.py:
    - Create model Reserve
Migrations for 'sysSetting':
  0001_initial.py:
    - Create model UserProfile

$ heroku run python3 manage.py migrate
Running `python3 manage.py migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.3948
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: main, userLogin
  Apply all migrations: sessions, admin, auth, contenttypes
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
    Creating table main_chargingmethod
    Creating table main_invoicetype
    Creating table main_delivertype
    Creating table main_currentrecord
  Installing custom SQL...
  Installing indexes...
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK
```

The outputs of `makemigrations` show that the following models are skipped:

```
ChargingMethod
InvoiceType
DeliverType
CurrentRecord
```

However, during `manage.py migrate`, only the tables in `main` are created. Others are skipped. What is the problem?

Comment: It's probably not the problem, but you should really be running makemigrations locally and committing the migrations to version control, then deploying and running migrate.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Daniel. You're right. I first perform `makemigrations` locally. And after pushing the project, I perform `migrate` remotely, and everything works fine now.